# Low quality animations matplotlib after saving

Tags: animation, matplotlib, julia

I have made a simulation in julia using matplotlib as a visual tool. When I use the command to display the animation

```
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=int(time[end]*10), interval=20, blit=false, repeat = false)
```

all is fine and the animation looks nice. However when I try to save it using

```
mywriter = animation.MencoderWriter()

anim[:save]("/home/maquinadt/Documentos/gas.mp4", writer = mywriter)
```

the video is saved with a very low quality (I mean it looks very slow compared with the "live" version).

I have played with the `fps` keyword of save but the result is the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adjusting the `bitrate` as well?  Take a look at the docstrings for the `MencoderWriter`:

http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.MencoderWriter

You should also be able to pass arguments to `mencoder` through the `extra_args` keyword argument.  Finally, I think the ffmpeg writer has nicer defaults, so you could also try that if you have ffmpeg installed.

Comment: Thanks for answering. ¿Do you recommend a particular value for bitrate? And what `extra_args` you recommend?

Comment: You're going to need to experiment for both options.  I'm not sure how you actually use `extra_args`, you will likely need to look at how the argument is actually passed to `mencoder` inside matplotlib.

Optionally, you can of course always write your frames to disk individually and then stitch them together manually using `mencoder` or `ffmpeg`.

Comment: ok @nathan12343 . Thanks for taking the time to answer. I am going to play around with the extra_args.